# Setting the cache in jQuery $.post() to be false?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$.post("php/tagNotifUnsub.php", $("#tagNotifUnsub").serialize(), function(){ 
            $('#tagSubDiv').load('tags.php #tagSubDiv', function(){$( "button, input:submit, input:button, a#jql, input:radio" ).button();});      
        });
```

I understand that $.post is just another name for $.ajax. And I know $.ajax has caching on by default. I want it to be uncached. How can I do that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`$.post` is not cached.

> Pages fetched with POST are never
>   cached, so the cache and ifModified
>   options in jQuery.ajaxSetup() have no
>   effect on these requests.

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Well this is not entirely true, Safari on IOS 6 has cached POST request, it is crazy but it is true. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results]

Answer (score 16):

[Partly right, Daniel A. White](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5542725)!

On devices running iOS6 and Safari, POST is also cached.

What you can do is the following:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   type: 'POST',
   headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You mention $.ajax

You can turn caching off for ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/myURL?",
        cache: false,
    });
```

Comment: I'm using a GET ajax call and this finally fixed the issue. For some reason some of the requests were being cached and I was getting incorrect data.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old problem that seems to pop up from time to time and I am always scratching my head.  This solution fixes the problem but it may not be suitable in all cases as it is in effect disabling a key feature of AJAX - The asynchronous feature.  That said and done for the cases where I have had this problem - *Apple products and Safari I'm looking at you especially* - setting the additional parameter of `async:false` in your jQuery AJAX request fixes the issue and actually solves the "No Alert on Post Callback" problem.

As I said if you absolutely rely on asynchronous functionality then this is not going to help you, but for many projects it will stop you pulling your hair out.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType,
  async:false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add NO CACHE to PHP file.

for example

```
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32278441)