# jQuery $.post execute success instead of error if connection to server is lost

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm using this code to connect to the server via jQuery

```
var jqxhr = $.post('@Url.Action("../CheckMessage")',  { 'MessageId': MessageId }, 
    function (data, s) {
        alert ('This is executed on success only - data: ' + data + 's: ' + s);
    }
)
.error(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("error"})
```

If I create a new exception in the server `.error` method is correctly executed, but if I take the server down, then `success` method is executed.
How can I check if the connection to the server was lost?

Comment: What server response code do you get when you "take the server down"... i suspect it's not a 500

Answer (score 0):

`Ajax` recall the cached data for subsequent request if you do not sepecify `cache` as false in the ajax setting. Try this `cache:false` using `$.ajax`.

```
$.ajax({
     url:  '@Url.Action("../CheckMessage")',
     data: { 'MessageId': MessageId }, 
     cache: false,
     success: function (data, s) {
        alert ('This is executed on success only - data: ' + data + 's: ' + s);
     },
     error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
       alert("error");
     }
});
```

.

Comment: Answer from another thread: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542701/setting-the-cache-in-jquery-post-to-be-false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542701/setting-the-cache-in-jquery-post-to-be-false)

$.post is not cached.

Pages fetched with POST are never cached, so the cache and ifModified options in jQuery.ajaxSetup() have no effect on these requests.

From [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

So, it still doesn't recognize a server lost.

Any ideas?